# Where is the NUnit XML output when using the NUnit GUI runner?

Tags: nunit

I am trying to run my NUnit tests from the NUnit GUI runner and I want to get the same xml report that I get from the console runner, but I can't find it anywhere.  Where is it?

When I click "File > Save Results" nothing happens. But this is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using an old version of the GUI, before saving XML was added. The "NUnit Gui Runner" was an experimental GUI that was dropped after version 0.7 as a separate package. It was incorporated into the "TestCentric GUI Runner", which is now in beta release for version 1.0.

The TestCentric GUI includes a standard GUI (looks like NUnit V2) as well as the experimental GUI. You can get it at https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-gui or on chocolatey.org.

The old package will be marked as deprecated as soon as the final 1.0 release of the replacement package is out.

Comment: Yes thank you! I was using the old one.  With this new one, you can look under Tools > Save Test Results and the TestResults.xml can be saved.